# If docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile both specify env vars which has precedence?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I have `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV NAME=Dockerfile-wins

CMD echo $NAME
```

and a `docker-compose.yml` with:

```
version: '3'

services:

  myservice:
    build: .
    container_name: myservice
    environment:
      - NAME=docker-compose-wins
```

when I run `docker-compose up myservice` which one will win out and **why**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docker-compose wins out as it overrides whats in the Dockerfile. What is specified in the Dockerfile is a default. and can be overridden by using the docker command which is what docker-compose does.

This is documented in the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

under the covers essentially docker-compose is running something like

```
docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE
```

Comment: Correct :) Environment Variables are used to pass values to the container and will overwrite the default value defined in Dockerfile. I wanted also to mention the "docker run -e" parameter.